# CSS: Gradient text colour?

Tags: css, gradient, mask

I'm trying to get some text to have a gradient colour, but I haven't a clue how. I'm trying to get it like this:

[image: Gradient image]

The only thing I have tried is `-webkit-mask`, but I couldn't get that working how I wanted it to. The other thing would be `-webkit-gradient` in the `color` property - is that possible?

Cross browser compatibility is fairly important, but not the end of the world. I'd prefer the text to be a solid colour in IE than to convert the entire thing into an image (there is quite a bit of text like this, some of it dynamic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For webkit based browsers (Chrome & Safari) :

```
.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#111));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

For IE & others:

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-gradient-text/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to do it other browsers, too? I'd like it if it worked in WebKit and Firefox minimum (although IE would be extremely nice).

Comment: Thanks, marked as solution. I won't use the link, as I would prefer it to just display a little differently than take away the ability to select text (although I guess that I could have another layer of text over all that with opacity 0?)

Comment: Why not to use modern `linear-gradient` syntax: `background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #111);`?