# Cross-browser text-color: gradient?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am looking for some lite JS, CSS solution how create gradient color for headlines. I don't have nodejs / react. Solution must working on IE11, Safari 7.1., Mozilla.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215915/css-gradient-text-colour

Comment: SVG would fit well too

Comment: @ericg no duplicate. Author have solution only for webkit.

Comment: @landsman the answer has a link to a solution for IE and other non-webkit browers http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-gradient-text/

Comment: @ericg sorry, it is ugly. I want dynamic text, no static png.