# Text gradient: cross-browser wrap text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linear-gradients

### 1. Summary

Gradiented text successful wrap by lines for me in Firefox, but not in another browsers.

---

### 2. Requirements

I need, that text gradient successful works in latest at April 2018 versions of these desktop and mobile browsers:

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Safari
- Opera

Internet Explorer and Opera Mini support not obligatory.

Any CSS or JavaScript/JQuery method will be suitable for me.

---

### 3. Example

Example: I need, that gradiented text `Suricate: Sacagawea: Blitz/Supeblitz/Brain Ring` text wrap by lines.

[**my code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215938/5951529):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>
            Document
        </title>
        <style>
        em {
         background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(red), to(black));
         background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, black);
         -webkit-background-clip: text;
         color: transparent;
         font-size: 5rem;
        }
                </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <em>
            Suricate: Sacagawea: Blitz/Supeblitz/Brain Ring
        </em>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### 4. Expected behavior

*(I use BrowserStack for cross-browser testing)*

- Samsung Galaxy S8, Android Nougat, Firefox 51:

[image: Firefox]

---

### 5. Non-expected behavior

- macOS High Sierra, Safari 11:

[image: macOS Safari]

- Samsung Galaxy S8, Android Nougat, Chrome 63:

[image: Chrome]

- IPhoneX, [**iOS and Safari**](https://www.lifewire.com/check-the-version-number-of-safari-446563) 11:

[image: iOS Safari]

---

### 6. Not helped

In all cases I get behavior as in *Non-expected behavior* section.

#### 6.1. Prefixes

Different prefixes as in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832318/5951529).

#### 6.2. CSS wrapping

`overflow-wrap`, `word-break`, `word-wrap` as in [**this article**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/):

```css
em {

  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;

}
```

#### 6.3. Gradient.Text.js

As in [**this article**](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Gradient-Text-Effect-jQuery.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>
            Document
        </title>
        <style>
         em {
          font-size: 5rem;
         }
        </style>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gradient-text/dist/jquery.gradient.text.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <em class="gradient-text"
       data-gradient-text-range="#f00, #000">Suricate: Sacagawea: Blitz/Supeblitz/Brain Ring</em>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no way of testing this but one thing i always try, if the different word breaks and wraps don't work, is the 'white-space' property.

Comment: @wazz: **Status: Still doesn't work for me** | **Steps to reproduce**: I try add to code in 3 item of my question [**all values of `white-space` property**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp). **Testing environment**: macOS High Sierra, Safari 11. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix:

```
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
```

I almost cried with joy when I found this.

Simon